# JQuery (this).data("id") returns undefined output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two files, load-request.php, and load-data.php, the delete button in load-request.php returns an undefined value when I click on the delete button to get its value.
kindly advise, why I am not getting the value.

Load-request.php

```
<form>
    <table class="table" id="main" border="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td id="table-load">
                <input type="button" id="load-button" value="Load Data">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <table class="table" width="55%">
            <tr>
                <td id="table-data"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { //ajax to load the table
            $("#load-button").on("click", function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "load-data.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#table-data").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
            $(document).on("click", ".delete-btn", function() {
                console.log($(this).find("data-id"));
                var pn = $(this).attr('value');
                alert(pn);

            });
        });
    </script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

load-data.php

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $output .= "<tr><td>{$row["pname"]}</td><td>{$row["src"]}</td><td>{$row["dst"]}</td><td>{$row["ports"]}</td><td>{$row["inzone"]}</td><td>{$row["outzone"]}<td><button Class='delete-btn' **data-id'{$row["pname"]}**'>Delete</button></td></tr>";
}
$output .= "</table>";
echo $output;
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What does your HTML look like from your php? You seem to be missing an `=` for `data-id={$row["pname"]}`

Comment: i think you miss an =

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: added this = but still same result,From my load-data.php which is handling Database connection and transactions, I can fetch all the records in the table in load-request.php, only issue is the button created in load-data.php is not return the value. while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  $output .= "<tr><td>{$row["pname"]}</td><td>{$row["src"]}</td><td>{$row["dst"]}</td><td>{$row["ports"]}</td><td>{$row["inzone"]}</td><td>{$row["outzone"]}<td><button Class='delete-btn' data-id='{$row["pname"]}'>Delete</button></td></tr>.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery.ajax is [async](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming)) by default. You can see this clearly in the [Jquery.ajax documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
> true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to
> false.

so to solve your issue you need to

1. : make it sync instead of async :

```
$(document).ready(function() { //ajax to load the table
    $("#load-button").on("click", function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "data.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#table-data").html(data);
            },
            async: false
        });

        $(document).on("click", ".delete-btn", function() {
            console.log($(this));
            var pn = $(this).attr('data-id');
            alert(pn);

        });
    })
});
```

2. or you can listen to the document object

```
$(document).ready(function() { //ajax to load the table
    $("#load-button").on("click", function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "data.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#table-data").html(data);
                
            }
        });
    })
}).on("click", ".delete-btn", function() {
    console.log($(this));
    var pn = $(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(pn);
});
```

3. use a custom listener as following

```
$(document).ready(function() { //ajax to load the table

    function myCustomListener(that) {
        that.on("click", ".delete-btn", function() {
            console.log($(this));
            var pn = $(this).attr('data-id');
            alert(pn);
        });
    }

    $("#load-button").on("click", function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "data.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#table-data").html(data);

                myCustomListener($("#table-data"));
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: with this code, it's not populating all data from the SQL table, only one row in the table

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { //ajax to load the table
                $("#load-button").on("click", function() {
                   $.ajax({
                        url: "load-data.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "text",
                        success: function(data) {
                                                  $("#table-data").html(data);  }   }); });
                $(document).on("click", ".delete-btn", function() {
                   var pn = $(this).data("id" );
                    alert(pn); }); });

Comment: the one i pasted above is working, but still couldn't figure out what was the problem, now i can see the returned value in the alert

Comment: this was the main reason for not returning the value '=' operator,   data-id='{$row["pname"]}'

Comment: data-id'{$row["pname"]}' =====> data-id='{$row["pname"]}'

Comment: Dear All, Thank you very much for your quick help.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I don't use jQuery but I can tell that if an element is not attached to the DOM at the moment that you register the event, it won't subscribe to it. So maybe after you render the data you can register the event, this way the elements will listen to it. Something like this:

```js
$("#load-button").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "load-data.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#table-data").html(data);
            $(document).on("click", ".delete-btn", function() {
              console.log($(this).find("data-id"));
              var pn = $(this).attr('value');
              alert(pn);

          });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: still same error with your rendering suggestion :(